# How to encrypt jwt payload in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, encryption, jwt, jwe

I have this code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
         };
});

app.Map("/login/{username}", (string username) => 
{
    var claims = new List<Claim> {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username) };
    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: AuthOptions.ISSUER,
            audience: AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)),
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
            
    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
});

public class AuthOptions
{
    public const string ISSUER = "MyAuthServer"; 
    public const string AUDIENCE = "MyAuthClient"; 
    const string KEY = "mysupersecret_secretsecretsecretkey!123";   

    public static SymmetricSecurityKey GetSymmetricSecurityKey() => 
        new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KEY));
}
```

How do I encrypt the payload data in my token? Perhaps `TokenDecryptionKey` should be added to `options.TokenValidationParameters`, but how do I encrypt this token initially?

Comment: if you are using HTTPS (not HTTP) it is already encrypted.

Comment: @jdweng I save my jwt in cookies, and if I then log in to jwt.io then I can safely view the payload since it is not encrypted

Comment: HTTPS will automatically encrypt and decrypt.  You are then reading the payload inside an app and do not have to worry about the data being secured.  The app is running on its on process and other processes cannot access the data.

Comment: @jdweng 1. HTTP application. 
2. The token is stored in a cookie, after which it is added to the header with middleware, therefore, if you steal cookies, you can find out the payload.

Comment: The cookie is encrypted in HTTPS (headers are encrypted) so you cannot steal the cookie.  The cookie is also stored so only the one user has access to the cookie.  Also make sure you do not put any pertinent info in the URL which is not encrypted.

Comment: @jdweng 1. I use http, not https 2. If cookies and headers are encrypted, then why can I view the cookies stored for this site in my browser, see the token there, and then calmly view the payload on the same jwt.io

Comment: HTTP is not encrypted.  Nobody these days uses HTTP is they are concerned about security.  Besides you are asking how to encrypt the payload which is the body and the headers will not be encrypted.  The cookies/token are in the headers.  Use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can encrypt the payload in a token, so that you don't see it jwt.io but at the same time, you could get data from the payload in the code:

```
public class AuthOptions
{
    public const string ISSUER = "MyAuthServer";
    public const string AUDIENCE = "MyAuthClient";
    const string KEY = "SecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeyS"; //64 symbols
    public static SymmetricSecurityKey GetSymmetricSecurityKey() =>
        new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KEY));
}
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

            ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,
            ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
            IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
            TokenDecryptionKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
        };
    });
```

Controller or another place:

```
string CreateJwt(string username)
{
    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
    };

    var jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().CreateJwtSecurityToken(
        AuthOptions.ISSUER,
        AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
        new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
        null,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
        null,
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
        encryptingCredentials: new EncryptingCredentials(AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), JwtConstants.DirectKeyUseAlg, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512)
    );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In ASP.NET 6, you can encrypt the JWT payload by using the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package, which provides functionality for working with JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). Here's a step-by-step guide on how to encrypt the JWT payload in ASP.NET 6:

1. Add the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package to your project. You can do this by adding the following package reference to your project file (`.csproj`):
2. In your code, import the necessary namespaces:

   using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
   using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
   using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
3. Load the X.509 certificate used for encryption. You can load it from a file, store, or any other source. Here's an example of loading it from a file:

```cs
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("path_to_certificate.pfx", "certificate_password");
```

4. Create an instance of `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` to handle token processing:

```cs
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
```

5. Create a `TokenValidationParameters` object to specify the token validation parameters. Set the `IssuerSigningKey` property to the public key of the certificate:

```cs
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    IssuerSigningKey = new X509SecurityKey(certificate.PublicKey),
    // Other validation parameters...
};
```

6. Create a JWT token with the desired claims and encrypt it using the certificate's private key:

```cs
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
        new Claim("claim_name", "claim_value"),
        // Add other claims as needed...
    }),
    // Other token descriptor properties...
};

var token = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);
token.EncryptingCredentials = new X509EncryptingCredentials(certificate);

var encryptedToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

7. The `encryptedToken` now contains the encrypted JWT payload.

Remember to handle exceptions and error cases appropriately, and customize the code according to your specific requirements.

Please note that this code assumes you have an X.509 certificate that you want to use for encryption. You'll need to obtain or create a certificate, and make sure you have access to its private key for encryption purposes.

I hope this helps you encrypt the JWT payload in ASP.NET 6! Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: X.509 certificate where can I get it?

Comment: And then how do I make sure that this token is automatically decrypted, where I need to receive a payload from the server?

Comment: services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
...
                IssuerSigningKey = /* Your signing key, if using symmetric encryption */,
                // Set the X.509 certificate for decryption
                TokenDecryptionKey = new X509SecurityKey(/* Your X.509 certificate */),
            };
        });